# How can I tell which marvel sites I have investigated already?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I'm trying to wrap up the *Visions in the Storm* quest. I have been sending my explorers, soldiers, and pet sea dragon to various hydrocoral brains, but I have a hard time finding out which one I'm missing. (I had some of my units doing automated exploration, and now I'm not sure which one I might have not visited yet.) The only way I seem to be able to tell whether I had investigated one before is by revisiting it with a unit and checking whether I'm able to investigate it. This is consuming a lot of moves of my units of course.
Is there a better indicator to tell which hydrocoral brains I have already investigated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're tracking quest objects on the map. Look for the eye icon in the top-left of the minimap, then open the icon menu and check "Expedition Sites".

[image: Icon menu showing "Expedition Sites" option.]

With this option on, marvel sites will show a blue diamond-shaped icon on the main map. A white center indicates that your units have explored that site, and a black center indicates that they haven't. (These happen to be the floating alien structures from "Ice and Conquest", but the icons are the same for all marvels.)

[image: White diamond = explored] Explored site.
[image: Black diamond = not yet explored] Unexplored site.